# Why tests passes individually and fail on terminal CLI execution?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, unit-testing, dart, flutter-test

I'm writting tests to ensure a set of initialization rules on an object with an optional parameter, like the one below:

```
part 'example.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(createToJson: false)
class Example {
  String req1;
  String req2;
  String? opt;

  Example({required this.req1, required this.req2, this.opt});

  factory Example.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ExampleFromJson(json);
}
```

My .g.dart is the following:

```
Example _$ExampleFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return Example(
    req1: json['req1'] as String,
    req2: json['req2'] as String,
    opt: json['opt'] as String?,
  );
}
```

The following two tests passes when executed individually, through android studio GUI, and fail through in `flutter test` CLI execution.

```
    test('should fail when json without req1 is provided', () {
      var testJson = {
        'req2': 'a-req2',
      };
      expect(() => Example.fromJson(testJson), throwsA(isA<TypeError>()));
    });

    test('should fail when json without req2 is provided', () {
      var testJson = {
        'req1': 'a-req1',
      };
      expect(() => Example.fromJson(testJson), throwsA(isA<TypeError>()));
    });
```

Dart version from android studio and terminal are different (2.10 and 2.17.6), but the execution also fails in our CI, which has the same version of GUI, which works.

The error presented when the pipeline executes is the following:

```
Expected: throws <Instance of 'TypeError'>
    Actual: <Closure: () => Example>
     Which: returned <Instance of 'Example'>
```

So the object does get instantiated, even with null value in required fields.

Any idea why?

Comment: Null-safety was not enabled by default until Dart 2.12.  Your code should not be working in Dart 2.10 at all unless you specifically enabled it (which at the time was an experimental feature).

Comment: I don't know why your test would be failing with Dart 2.17.6.  I copied-and-pasted the code you've shown and cannot reproduce any failure with Dart 2.17.6.  Perhaps you aren't observing what you think you're observing, or perhaps the example you've shown is not an accurate representation of the code you're actually testing (either of which is likely if your tests are somehow seem to be working in Dart 2.10).